# What is a clean LINQ query to get items with no child items?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, chaining

I have a query below that works but was wondering if there is a cleaner way to implement it.

```
var query = Context.Alerts
                .Where(a => a.AlertsDismisseds.Where(d => d.AlertID == a.AlertID)
                .Count() == 0)
                .Select(a => a);
```

I am looking to select all the Alerts from a table if there are not in the AlertsDismisseds table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Select(a => a)` is useless, it's an identity projection...

Comment: it's not useless per se, but in this case it is (you can use it to hide the implementation, as `AsEnumerable` simply returns the iterator passed in, allowing caller to cast to the implementation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = Context.Alerts
                .Where(a => !Context.AlertsDismissed.Any(d => d.AlertID == a.AlertID))
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated already by Femaref, you can use:

```
var query = Context.Alerts
            .Where(a => !Context.AlertsDismissed.Any(d => d.AlertID == a.AlertID));
```

Here's why:

- `Any(predicate)` returns true if any items in the IEnumerable pass the predicate (and will do so as soon as one does), so this is preferable to `Count(predicate) > 0` (which will enumerate the entire sequence).
- Select() performs a projection, converting an `IEnumerable<Input>` into and `IEnumerable<Output>`, so `Select(a => a)` actually does nothing.